# Remote RMX on Jboss 1.3.5.Final-redhat-1 - LogManager wat not properly installed

Tags: java, jboss, rmi, jconsole

Dears,
I'm struggling while trying to connect to Remote RMX.
Already found that additional Java start arguments must be added:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333
```

But also it generates another problem where LogManager must be specified.

So to JAVA_OPTS I also added already:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xbootclasspath/p:%JBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logmanager\main\jboss-logmanager-1.5.2.Final-redhat-1.jar
```

But yet I'm getting this error:

```
14:21:24,061 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.5.Final-
redhat-1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you
must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanage
r.LogManager")
        at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:312)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:460)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas what else could be checked or added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that due to jboss customizations we are not able to run native JMX remote connection.

I used **jolokia** addon along with **hawtio** app to monitor server resources remotely.